# Mocking node_module with jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

I am mocking `rfx-core` node module.

I create mock file in path: `<rootDir>/__mocks__/rfx-core.js`

```
import core from 'rfx-core';

jest.genMockFromModule('core');
module.exports = core;
```

I get an error: `Cannot find module 'core' from 'rfx-core.js'`

from code line `jest.genMockFromModule('core');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need complex mock implementation you can avoid writing a manual mock.
Just add `jest.mock('rfx-core');` in your test file and all the `rfx-core` methods will be replaced with mock functions.

Answer (score 2):

Don't import the module you are mocking, just call `jest.genMockFromModule()` on the module name:

```js
module.exports = jest.genMockFromModule('rfx-core');
```